# After pushing to a remote server to do a "hg update"?

Tags: ssh, mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

After every pushing to remote repo, I have to connect to a remote server  and manually run "hg update". How to avoid it, and make it in automatic mode?

In a similar question was the decision to add to hgrc this lines

```
[hooks] 
changegroup = hg update >&2
```

but it doesn't helps me.

Here is how my hgrc file looks now:

```
[paths]
default = https://erniesto77:******@bitbucket.org/asapogov/fastorlab
default-push = ssh://root@193.124.50.21//var/www/fastorlab

[tortoisehg]
postpull = update
confirmpush = True

[hooks]
changegroup = hg update >&2
```

Comment: The original answer should be correct, but the hook has to be added to the server-side repository's `.hg/hgrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Thanks to [Reimer Behrends](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480466/reimer-behrends)

> The original answer should be correct, but the hook has to be added **to the server-side** repository's